# Magento 2 convert object to array

Tags: magento2, error, magento-2.1.4, conversion, docblock

I am trying to convert a `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` object to an array using `\Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter`.
I think it is not relevant here but I am using `Magento CE 2.1.4`

Here is the code I use :

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter;      

public function __construct(
    [...]
    ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $dataObjectConverter
) {
    [...]
    $this->dataObjectConverter = $dataObjectConverter;
}

public function get()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order */
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);

    /** @var array $data */
    $data = $this->dataObjectConverter->toFlatArray($order);
}
```

But here is the error I got :

> Getter return type must be specified using @return annotation. See Magento\Sales\Model\Order::getPayment()

If we take a look at `\Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor::getGetterReturnType()` there is this line :

```
$returnAnnotations = $methodDocBlock->getTags('return');
```

Which is using `\Zend\Code\Reflection\DocBlockReflection::getTags()` to list all DockBlock tags and check if there is a `return`

Now if we take a look at `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::getPayment()` here is the actual function declaration :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getPayment()
{
    [...]
}
```

To fix this issue I have to manually add the `@return` tag to `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::getPayment()`

According to https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/inheritance.html#methods the `@return` tag is subject to the inheritance so I should not have to put the `@return` tag in addition to the `@inheritdoc` one.

---

My questions are simple :

- Is that a bug?
- Am I using the wrong method to convert object to
  array in `Magento 2`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have to use the Interface Type for converting, since as API, it should have all the return types specified

try to call the function like this

```
$data = $this->dataObjectConverter->toFlatArray($order, [], \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class);
```

If you do not set a type, the class of the actual object will be used: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Api/ExtensibleDataObjectConverter.php#L44

Comment: Good catch this is it! Thank you for your answer

Comment: @David-, what is the fix for this error in console in IE,Object doesn't support property or method 'from'